# Download files of devices that connected into my WiFi Hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, superuser

Is it possible to download or watch the directories of the devices that connected into my WiFi hotspot ? or  Is there any way to collect personal data from the connected devices ? . Please **NOTE THAT I'VE A ROOTED ANDROID DEVICE WITH VERSION 4.1.2**. I am just curious about the possibilities. Just to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it is possible to control/watch over every data transferred by just analyzing the traffic. To do so you could use something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), but then a lot of Internet traffic today is encrypted, which would make it impossible to gain anything from it.

To access the data of connected devices would require certain other tools and would very likely be considered as hacking and illegal.

Comment: "To access the data of connected devices would require certain other tools" - you would need to exploit a security vulnerability to do this.